# Why use Vue CLI for Babel and ESLint?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I am just starting out with Node.js and Vue.js, and I noticed that Vue.js has a Vue CLI tooling kit (whatever that means) which gives you a scaffolding project (don't need it I think?) but it also adds ESLint and Babel.

The thing is, it adds them like this:

```
"plugins": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": {},
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": {
      "config": "airbnb",
      "lintOn": ["save", "commit"]
    }
}
```

What is the difference between Vue's Babel `@vue/cli-plugin-babel` and installing Babel using NPM? Why do `vue add cli-plugin-eslint` instead of `npm install eslint`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most important difference is that Vue CLI (and it's plugins) doesn't just add tools to your project but also provide configuration for the tools added (webpack/babel/eslint etc.) with sensible defaults (while still allowing you to fine-tune it)

So you can spend more time developing your app instead of figuring out how to setup dev/prod build tool chain...

Tools like Babel and ESLint are configured to work with Vue but it doesn't mean they work only for Vue specific features (for example Vue single file components). You can add pure JavaScript file into your project and Babel and ESLint will still work with it.

You can use some `boilerplate` or template for that but Vue CLI is better because it allows seamless updates to the tooling and configuration during whole project lifetime (instead of generating structure and config for you at the beginning and leave future updates to you).

For example lets say your project is using SASS in VUE single file components. You need a `sass-loader` Webpack plugin for that. Then `sass-loader` maintainers decide they need to change structure of their configuration (as happened [recently](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0)). If your project is based on the template of some kind, you can udpate to newer version of `sass-loader` but you'll also need to figure out what changes in configuration are needed to make it work again. If you are using Vue CLI (and CLI team decides to update to newest version of `sass-loader`), you just update Vue CLI (or it's plugin) and you good to go (because someone on Vue CLI team figured out what needs to be changed and done it)

If you are just starting with Node/Vue, it's highly recommended to base your project on Vue CLI instead of trying to start from scratch....

Comment: what does eject mean? does using Babel and ESLint as plugins of Vue CLI mean they will only work for Vue files or projects? If I was to create a Typescript `.ts` file with nothing to do with Vue within the same project, do the Babel and ESLint packages still work?

Comment: `eject` is the term used for the projects based on `create-react-app`. `create-react-app` is something like Vue CLI but for React projets. It manages tooling configuration for you. Ejecting means `stop managing configuration for me, give me all configs so i can change it myself`

Comment: Yes, Babel and ESLint will still work for your `.ts`. Just make sure to add TypeScript support when generating the project with Vue CLI....